# Naming/Capitalization usage in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

much to quite a few people's disappointment. I've decided to learn Ruby on Rails (I've been told by many people it's pointless to learn it, but ruby seems easy to get into and rails is a fun framework).

So I'm just now slowly starting to wrap my head around the naming convention with singular being used for the model and plural being used for the controller.

One thing I'm having a bit of trouble finding concise information on is Capitalization vs lowercase usage.

Example being

`@order = Order.create(order_date: Time.now, customer_id: @customer.id)`

Why exactly is 'Order.create' capitalized but not 'order_date'?

When to invoke capitalization has really got me confused when I use the rails console. I don't know when I'm suppose to be capitalizing or why. I want to say it too has to do with the model/controller naming scheme but neither of them are plural so that can't be the answer right?

Thanks for any help that is given, I really would/do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a ruby thing actually. In ruby you use capitalization (camel case) for class and module names. And snake_case for method and variable names.

In your specific case Order is a class, create is a method, @order is an instance variable. order_date and customer_id are symbols that represent the columns on the database.

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to ask about @order as well. So are instance variables like local variables that only work within the place they're defined correct?

Comment: Instance variables are available in a object's context. As the name indicates (an instance of a class -> an object).

Answer (score 2):

- `CamelCase` is used for classes and modules (e.g. `String`, `Array`, etc.)
- `snake_case` is used for variables and methods (symbols are also usually `snake_case`)
- `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` is used for naming constants (e.g. `STDOUT`)

Comment: Never heard of SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE being called that :) but seems adequate.

Answer (score 2):

This is to do with naming conventions in Ruby and/or Rails.

Typically:

- Create classes, modules using `CamelCase`.
- Create methods, variables using `underscore_case`.
- Create constants using `UPPER_UNDERSCORE_CASE`.

Take a look at different methods available in `ActiveSupport` to convert a string into various cases. http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/String/camelize

[Read Naming and Schema Conventions at Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions).

[A more succinct information](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7).

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the resources. Found another thread on some good Rails (and Ruby) reading material and will add these to the list. I'm currently unemployed so I've been spending 8hrs+ a day on this. And all of the answers definitely help. Got tired of being told I can't learn to program.